# Selecting .NET Target Framework in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to select target framework from the solution explorer, however all I can see is ".NET Standard 1.0" to 2.0 as available target. I've updated VS to the latest version (15.7.4) and have selected ".NET Desktop Development" workload in the installer. .NET 4-4.6 dev tools also already installed. So why can't I select them?

Comment: Do you mean you've gone into the [project properties](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC359535.png) and you're trying to change it there?

Comment: Which version do you want to select? 4.4.6?

Comment: Is the project a .NET Core solution or a .NET 4.x?   I don't believe you can switch between Core and 4.x.

Answer (score 4):

You've created a ".NET Standard" project and those are the only currently existing versions of the [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

It sounds like what you want to create is a "standard" .NET project which is any of the options found under Windows Desktop in the New Project dialog (though none are by that name).  This will give you the option of selecting which version of the .NET Framework you want to code against:

[image: Visual Studio 2017 New Project Dialog]

Comment: Thanks very much. It solves many problems. BTW what is the difference between ".NET Standard" project and the "standard" .NET?

Comment: No problem.  Check out the link in the answer, it will explain what .NET Standard is but to get the gist, think of it as a standard like HTML or CSS with versions and that makes the .NET Framework an implementation of the standard.  Different versions of the framework implement different versions of the standard.